# How to have a result from Rest api in json

Tags: json, angular, rest, ionic3

it's the first time that I use Ionic 3 and Angular 5.

I want do a simple call to a rest api, and display the results in a list.

I saw that it's necessary to create a provider, which is responsible to do the calls.

Navigating in google, I saw an example, and my provider is:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
/*
  Generated class for the PeopleServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PeopleServiceProvider {

  dati : string
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello PeopleServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  load() {
  if (this.dati) {
    // already loaded data
    return Promise.resolve(this.dati);
  }

  // don't have the data yet
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
    // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
    // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.

    this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
      //.map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        console.log(data);
        this.dati = data["results"];
        resolve(this.dati);
      });
  });
}
}
```

Then I have my template, and all works fine. My question is more a doubt.

When I get response from api, to take the result I have to do:

```
data["results"]
```

I thought that I was able to do:

```
data.results
```

Am I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you got that exmple from? Please look here https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I solved creating an interface, but it's the only way to do that? Sorry but it's first time, and I want clearify all my doubts. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you're data is an object, you should be able to retrieve the result by doing either `data["results"]` or `data. result`, can we have a look at you server response?

Comment: the linked documentation has the answer to your question...

Comment: @YounesM I am using a fake api on web: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new HttpClient allow you to use typescript TypeChecking,

so you should create an interface describing your return :

```
interface MyReturnType {
  results: any // <-- i dont know your model
}

...

this.http.get<MyReturnType>('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
.subscribe(data => {
    this.dati = data.results;
});
```

Comment: thanks! I already tried and it works fine!!! As said in a comment of my own answer, it's the only way to use to do that I want?

Comment: If you don't add a type typescript see the return as an Object ( default type definition set by angular HttpClient ) and so you have to use the ["xxx"] notation